# Rasterizing an equation makes it low res

Tags: export, image, traditional-form, rasterize

I've checked some quick tutorials to export equations as images, and all of them use the function Rasterize, but when I try to follow this method I get a very low res image of the equation.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

[image: This is what happens.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask for a big image you also need to specify a high raster resolution. Like so:

```
eq = HoldForm[μ = (Subscript[μ, max] s^n)/(Subscript[k, s] + s^n)];
With[{size = 600},
  Rasterize[TraditionalForm[eq], RasterSize -> size, ImageSize -> size]]
```

[image: raster]